# Pandas Keyerror 'date' is defined code worked in the past but does not

Tags: python

This code worked perfectly fine the other day for scraping a website then I ran it today and it fails I have spent literally days on this trying to figure it out to no avail. I have also totally uninstalled and reinstalled Python and all required libraries to no avail. Any help would be appreciated below is the code and error:

Thanks for any help you could provide.

The error is:

> KeyError: 'date'

Code:

```
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import warnings
import json
import shutil
import os
from difflib import get_close_matches
import time
import imdb
import datetime

# creating an instance of the IMDB()
##ia = imdb.IMDb()
ia = imdb.Cinemagoer()
# Using the Search movie method

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def get_movie_name(name):
    try:
        items = []
        while len(items) == 0 and len(name) > 0:
            time.sleep(2)
            items = ia.search_movie(name)
            if len(items) == 0:
                name = name.split(' ')
                name = name[:-1]
                name = ' '.join(name)

        closest_match = get_close_matches(name, [str(i) for i in items])
        if len(closest_match) ==0:
            return False
        else:
            return closest_match[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False

def read_inputs():
    f = open('config.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    return data
    


data = read_inputs()

download_folder = 'C:\\Users\\jerem\\Downloads'

date  = data["date"]
username = data["username"]   
password = data["password"]   

# initialize the Chrome driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging",'--headless','--disable-gpu'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options,executable_path = "chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.bd25.eu/index.php")
#username
##driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='lista'][@type='text']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']").send_keys(username)
##driver.find_element('type',"text").send_keys(username)


#password
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password)
#submit
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']").click()
#list of nzbs
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'List of NZBs').click()
movie_df,final_df = pd.DataFrame(),pd.DataFrame()
get_url = driver.current_url
for page in range(1,int(data['page_number_max'])):
    try:
        if page > 1:
            add_on = '&order=3&by=2&pages='+str(page)
            driver.get(get_url+add_on)
        body = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr")
        all_text = body.text
        y = all_text.split('\n')
        
        for i in range(330,430):
            movie_df = movie_df.append({'text':y[i]},ignore_index=True)
            value_list = y[i].split(' ')
            name = value_list[1:-7]
            name = ' '.join(name)
            if value_list[-3] != 'Upload':
                final_df = final_df.append({'date':value_list[-3],
                                        'name':name},ignore_index=True)
            value_list  = []
        print(str(page)+' page is done')
        
    except:
        break


#final_df = final_df[1:]
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%d/%m/%Y')
final_df['Upload_date'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['date'],dayfirst=True)
final_df = final_df.loc[final_df['Upload_date'] > date]

for i in range(len(final_df)):
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'List of NZBs').click()
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchinput").send_keys(final_df['name'].iloc[i])
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']").click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@src='images/download.gif']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        space_list = final_df['name'].iloc[i].split(' ')
        foldername = '.'.join(space_list)
        try:
            list_of_folder = [x for x in os.listdir(download_folder)]
            closest_match = get_close_matches(foldername, list_of_folder)
            src = closest_match[0]
        except:
            time.sleep(2)
            print('waiting for download')
            list_of_folder = [x for x in os.listdir(download_folder)]
            closest_match = get_close_matches(foldername, list_of_folder)
            src = closest_match[0]


        
        ##click on link to open password
        driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, final_df['name'].iloc[i]).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        ##driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ty').click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='button']").click()
        password_to_save = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='thanks_div']").text
        while len(password_to_save)==0:
            password_to_save = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='thanks_div']").text
            print('getting password')
            time.sleep(2)
        print('got password')
        movie_name = get_movie_name(final_df['name'].iloc[i])
        if movie_name == False:
            movie_name = final_df['name'].iloc[i]
        print(movie_name)
        try:
            # Destination
            try:
                dest = movie_name + ' password='+password_to_save+'.rar'
                # Renaming the file
                os.rename(download_folder+src, download_folder+dest)
            except:
                try:
                    dest = movie_name+'.rar' 
                    os.rename(download_folder+src, download_folder+dest)
                except:
                    try:
                        movie_name = ''.join(e for e in movie_name if e.isalnum())
                        dest = movie_name + ' password='+password_to_save+'.rar'
                        #dest = movie_name+'.rar' 
                        os.rename(download_folder+src, download_folder+dest)  
                    except:
                        movie_name = ''.join(e for e in movie_name if e.isalnum())
                        dest = movie_name + '.rar'
                        os.rename(download_folder+src, download_folder+dest)  
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        try:
            print('renamed file')
            shutil.move( download_folder+dest, data['target_directory_file'])

            # get description
            body = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr")
            a  = body.text
            soup  = BeautifulSoup(a)
            description = (soup.prettify())
            desc_index  =description.find('Description')
            screen_index = description.find('Screenshots')
            final_description = description[desc_index:screen_index]
            #create_info_file(movie_name,description)
            os.chdir(data['target_directory_info_file'])
            with open(movie_name+'.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(final_description)
                f.write('password = '+password_to_save)

            print(i)
        except:
            print('already exists')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3800, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Desktop\Final\BD25 Scraper\project2.py", line 104, in <module>
    final_df['Upload_date'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['date'],dayfirst=True)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'date'
```

I am expecting the output to allow me to scrape all entries after a date I put in.

This code worked a few days ago, I have made no edits now it doesn't.

Would someone be able to help me figure out why it cannot find 'date' when I have it defined?

Comment: If the code hasn't changed... then the data must have changed.. no?

Comment: `final_df['date']` is created inside a `try` block. Can you check that the block is being executed and that you have indeed a `date` column after that?